# Continuous red dot on reopen votes

Tags: support, bug, review, re-open

On this question there are many questions on meta MSE.

[image]

And I hope it's not a duplicate. It had never occurred to me that this red dot shown in the green rectangle in the upper right corner was continually present despite having made the proper revisions. But how do I remove it if I don't have any revision in the queue ?

Please I use translator and hope my question is understandable. Otherwise I ask the kindness to fix it in correct English language.